# Optimization Problem: You are Designing a poster with 50 s. in of printing, a 4 in. margin at the top and bottom and a 2 in. margin on each side.

Tags: calculus

You are Designing a poster with 50 s. in of printing, a 4 in. margin at the top and bottom and a 2 in. margin on each side. What overall dimensions will minimize the amount of paper used?

I am using these three steps:

1) Get two equations

2) Plug one equation into the other and simplify

3) Take the derivative of this new equation and set equal to zero to solve

My first equation is Area of the entire poster which is A= (y-4)(x-8). My second equation is for area of the minimize area: xy=50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the height of the print be $y$. Let the width of the print be $x$.

Then $xy = 50$.

Now we need  the dimensions of the entire poster (including margins): these will be given by the poster's height of $y + 2\cdot 4$, and the poster's width by $x + 2\cdot 2$.

Then we want to minimize the area of the poster (with margins), knowing the posters area will be the height of the poster times the width of the poster: $$A = (y + 8)(x+4)$$

Using our first equation, we get that $y  = \dfrac{50}{x}$.

So $$A(x) = \left(\frac {50}x + 8\right)(x + 4)= 50+8x+\frac{200}{x} + 32= 8x +\frac{200}{x}+ 82$$

Find $A'(x)$, and the value of $x$ which minimizes $A(x)$.

Then solve for the dimensions of the poster: width $x + 4$, and then using that width solve for $y = \dfrac{50}{x}$. Then compute the height of the poster: $y +8$.

Comment: My A'(x) = $  -200 x^-2 +8 $ This is where I am stuck. Do I set this expression to zero?

Comment: $$\frac{-200}{x^2} + 8 = \frac{-200 + 8x^2}{x^2} = 0 \iff 8x^2 = 200 \iff x^2 = 25\iff \cdots$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got 8x^2 =200. Can you show me your steps? I factored the 8 out and got 8(25+x^2) / x^2

Comment: $\dfrac{-200 + x^2}{x^2} =0$ if and only if the numerator equals 0, that is if and only if $-200+8x^2 = 0\iff 8x^2 = 200 \iff x^2 = 25$. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you factor out $8$, in your numerator, you should get $\dfrac{8(x^2 - 25)}{x^2}$ which will = $0$ if and only if $8(x^2-25) = 0 \iff x^2 - 25 = 0 \iff x^2 = 25$. There are two solutions to this quadratic: $x=5$, $x=-5$, but the negative value needs to be thrown out because we are dealing with positive measures here. So we are left with $x=5 \implies$ the width of the poster needs to be $x+4 = 5+4 = 9$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hi Glenn, I am still a little confused at to why you are allowed to disregard the x^2 in the denominator. Can you relate this portion of the solution to an algebra concept since I would have never have thought to disregard the x^2 .

Comment: Provided $x\neq 0$ (in which case the derivative is undefined, nor would be $y$), we have $$\dfrac{ 8(x^2 - 25)}{x^2} = 0 \iff 8(x^2 - 25) = 0\cdot x^2 = 0 \implies 8(x^2 - 25) = 0 \iff x^2 - 25 = 0\iff\cdots$$

Comment: I can't really follow your solution when it comes to calculating x=5. I guess it is a basic math problem. Nonetheless, I pluged the positive 5 into the original y= 50/x and (x+4). My answer is 9 X 18 inches. Correct? Also, If you have any tutorials that can explain your last step it would be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Yes, you're correct with your solution. As for why $x=5$, we can also write $$x^2-25 = 0 \iff x^2-(5^2) = (x+5)(x-5) = 0 \implies x = -5 \text{ or } x = 5$$ Alternatively, $x^2 - 25 = 0 \iff x^2 = 25 \iff x = \pm \sqrt {25} = \pm 5$ However, $x$ must have positive measure (else, we'd have negative width of the text). So $x = 5$ is the only solution.)